# How can you paste multiple links / URL in a Python list

Tags: python, list, hyperlink, paste

So I have a list of links / URLs in a text document:

https://www.url1.com

https://www.url2.com

etc.

Is there any way to paste them faster in a Python list? Currently I copy one by one.

I'm using Pycharm Community.

I"m asking because I always have to:

1 - paste the link

2 - add the quotes

3 - add a "," after.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can read your text file like this

```
with open('links.txt', 'r') as reader:
    links = reader.read().split("\n")
```

Or you can use this code to print and copy that output

```
for link in links:
    print('"{}"'.format(link), end="")
    if(link != links[-1]):
        print(",", end="")
```

Output

```
"https://google.com","https://apple.com","https://stackoverflow.com/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that output needed is:

`["url1", "url2", "url3", ...., "urln"]`

Just read the complete file and use split function.

```
urls = None
with open("url_file.txt") as url_file:
    urls = url_file.read().split("\n")
    urls.remove("") #Removing empty end of line

print(urls) #This now contains the list of urls
```

If the output needed is a string of urls like:

`"url1,url2,url3,url4"`

Use the replace function:

```
urls = None
with open("url_file.txt") as url_file:
    urls = url_file.read().replace("\n", ",").strip(",")
    urls = urls.strip(",") #Removing extra comma at the end of string

print(urls) #This now contains the string of urls
```